# jQuery buttons and functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just started using jQuery earlier in my code to grab  and remove its contents. I am currently having trouble with my "Show nodes" button. The problem is that when it is unclicked, the nodes should be erased and then redrawn when the button is clicked again. I will also post my codepen below.

So far the clearing of the nodes only happens when I unselect "Show nodes" and then proceed to click either "n-1," "ground state," or "n+1." Here's the relevant code to this. Thanks guys.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kurtacus/pen/EXbYyZ

```js
var n = 1;

function drawNodes() {
  clearNodes();
  for (var m = 1; m < n; m++) {
    var nodeLocation = (m / n) * 400 + 150;
    document.getElementById("nodeDrawing").innerHTML += '<circle cx="' + nodeLocation + 'cy="150" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill = "red" / > ';
  }
  m = 1;
};

function clearNodes() {
  $("svg").find("g").empty(); //uses jQuery empty contents of <g>
};

function transformToSVG(n, coordinates) {
  clearNodes();
  if ($(showNodes).hasClass('active')) {
    drawNodes();
  } else if ($(showNodes).hasClass('inactive')) {
    clearNodes();
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="showNodes" type="button" onClick="jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').click(drawNodes())" value="Show nodes">
```

Comment: When you use `.click()` you're supposed to pass a function: `.click(drawNodes)`. What you have amounts to `click(undefined)`, since that is what `drawNodes()` returns.

Comment: your functions aren't (weren't) closed properly. cool graph btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onClick handler you set up on your Show nodes button toggles the active class,  but nothing is paying attention to the class changing, and nothing ever calls transformToSVG based on the show nodes click which is the function that looks at the class.

A quick (but not very pretty) way of doing this that seems to work in codepen is just to add a little more logic to the onClick.

```
<input 
    id="showNodes" 
    type="button" 
    onClick="jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').hasClass('active') ? drawNodes() : clearNodes()" value = "Show nodes">
```

Comment: I've seen the ? and : around a lot when searching for jQuery but I'm not sure what it means. Does the statement simply state "if this button is active then drawNodes() and if this button is inactive then clearNodes()"?

Comment: @allego It's called a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and yes,  it acts like a condensed if / else statement.  If the condition is true the code before the colon is executed.  If it's false,  the code after is.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying, incorrectly, use jQuery to bind an event handler to the button after the button is clicked.

Try this.

```
<input id="showNodes" type="button" onclick="jQuery(this).toggleClass('active'); drawNodes();"
```

Additionally, the syntax for what you were trying to accomplish:

```
jQuery('#showNodes').click(function() { drawNodes();});
```

Typically event binding with jQuery wrapped inside of a function that will be called when the document is ready.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#showNodes').click(function() { drawNodes();});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply especially for all the syntax information. I will surely find this useful later on in other projects.